# Rank of full $R$-lattices

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $R$ is a Dedekind domain, with fraction field $K$. $L/K$ is a finite separable extension. Let $n=[L:K]$.

A full $R$-lattice in $L$ is a *finitely generated* $R$-submodule $\Lambda$ of $L$ satisfying $K\cdot \Lambda=L$. $\Lambda$ is $R$-torsion free since $L$ is a field.

My question is:
**(A) Must $\operatorname{rank}_R\Lambda$ (i.e. the cardinality of a minimal $R$-basis of $\Lambda$) be $n$?**

It is apparently $\ge n$ since $\Lambda$ spans $L$. I am considering
**(B) Does $R$-linearly independence imply $K$-linearly independence?**
If so, we get $\operatorname{rank}_R\Lambda\le n$.

(**Edit**: (B) cannot imply the assertion, we need (B'): Does a minimal $R$-basis $K$-linearly independent?)

Any suggestion (proof, counterexample, ...)  will be appreciated.

Comment: You surely mean "a full $R$-lattice in $L$ is a **finitely generated** $R$-submodule..."

Comment: As $\Lambda$ may not be a free module, its rank is not necessarily the size of a minimal basis.

Comment: Yes, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank of a (finitely generated) module $M$ over an integral domain $R$ is defined to be the cardinality of a maximal subset $B\subset M$ of elements that are linearly independent over $R$. This is the same as the dimension of the vector space $M\otimes_R K=M_0$ (localisation of $M$ at $0$), where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Hence by definition a full $R$-lattice has rank equal to $[L:K]$ in the situation considered. Separability of $L|K$ is not needed.

Comment: If $B$ is a maximal linearly independent set, then it spans $M$. So the cardinality of a minimal $R$-basis of $M$, say $B'$, is smaller than the cardinality of $B$. Since $\# B\le n$, we have $n \le \# B' \le \# B \le n$. Can we draw the conclusion that the two definitions of rank is the same?

Comment: It is not true, that a maximal linearly independent set spans $M$: consider the case $L=K$ and $M$ an ideal of $R$. Since in general Dedekind domains are not principal ideal domains one can find examples, where $M$ is not generated by one element. However its rank equals one.